# Form Submit doesn't work with a relative positioned div

Tags: jquery, forms

I've got an HTML `<form>` inside a `div` which is displayed `position:relative` by jQuery/CSS when we click on the `<div id="news">` (the black background on the top of the frame)

jQuery works fine, but, when you click on `<input type="submit">`, nothing happens. Data are not sent to the php file for treatment.

I tried with GET and POST method, nothing...

I've made a JSFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jcdarocha/64FW4/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="news" class="hidden">
        <article>
            <form action="form-news.php" method="post" id="form-news">
                <label for="news-name">Name :</label>
                <input type="text" id="news-name" name="news-name">
                <input type="submit" name="submit-news" value="Ok" id="submit-news">
            </form>
            <div id="news_added"></div>
        </article>
        <br class="clear">
    </div><br class="clear">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#container").click(function(){
        $("#news").removeClass("hidden");
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

CSS:

```
#container{background:black; position:relative;}
#news{position:absolute; top:100px; left:50px;}
.clear{clear:both;}
.hidden{display:none;}
```

Comment: Please always come back to proof-read your OP after posting... all of your inline code was invisible to us because you failed to format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove  `return false;` in your JavaScript code and it's working just fine.

hope this help

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Ayush - It looks like an answer to me... it might not be an answer that you agree with, but it's attempting to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your event is bubbling, so the click on the button is returning false..
to fix this add event prevent propagation.

I have also updated your code to use .on instead of .click..

http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/64FW4/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on('click', '#container', function (e) {
       console.log("hit"); //check the log you will see that even the input will trigger this console.log.
       e.preventPropagation; //this stops bubbling.
       if (!$(e.target).is(':input')) { //maybe you want to check if the DIV is the only thing clicked? here is where to do this.
           $("#news").removeClass("hidden");
           return false;
       }
    });
});
```